# Why use MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've done a bit of searching, but never found a good answer to this question.

**If I have access to SupportMapFragment, why would I ever use MapFragment?**

I know that MapFrag is supported only api level 11 and higher. However, what is the point of it if there's a version of it that supports a wider range of devices? In the same vein, does SupportMapFrag have any notable limitations? Is it less efficient or something?

I would happily just use MapFragment, but according to the [Android Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) page, 33% of devices are running Gingerbread (api 10)... which is still a substantial amount of people that I don't want to alienate.

Thanks in advance.

--

*Side note: Long time stackoverflow reader, but this is my first post. I know how much you guys hate questions that could have been answered by some light googling. I genuinely tried looking! lol, but I would still appreciate links to sites that answer this question sufficiently.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SupportMapFragment belongs to the v4 support library, contrary to the default MagFragment that is a native component in Android.

SupportMapFragment will support more Android versions, but it is also an additional library you have to add in your project, so I think it really depends on the Android versions you are targeting:

- On recent versions, the default components should be enough
- On older versions you will need to install the v4 support library and maybe others

Here are 2 links from the Android documentation giving details about the support libraries:

**Support Library Features**

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

**Support Library Revisions**

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Ah, I see! So whenever Gingerbread becomes much less popular, I suppose SupportMapFragment will probably be depreciated and MapFrag will be the standard because of its nativity?

Comment: I guess yes, I am not sure if they plan to remove or not old components from the support library or if they just keep adding the new ones inside.